# CentOS8 nginx: [emerg] bind() failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: nginx, bind, ip-address, centos8

01/17/2020
I installed CentOS 8 on two separate servers, one a cloud server and the other a dedicated server.  In both cases, Nginx would not automatically start when the server was rebooted.  The /var/log/boot.log of both indicated Network Manager was started before Nginx, but they apparently run in parallel and Nginx was activating before the network initialized.  This caused Nginx to error out with 'Cannot assign requested address'.  If I manually started Nginx after the system was booted, it initialized without an issue.  I was able to determine a solution and will post that as an answer so I can mark it as solved.  Since it was consistent on two totally unrelated installs, I'm sure others will have the same issue and be searching for an answer that I wasn't finding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change worked for me on both servers:
Edit the **/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service** file

Change the default:
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

To:
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target **network-online.target**
**Wants=network-online.target**

This forces Nginx to wait until the network is online before starting.

Based on information found on this page:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started